# Python - trying to remove repeated values, but "unhasable type: list"

Tags: python

Here is what I have so far:

```
def remove_duplicates(values):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for value in values:
        # If value has not been encountered yet,
        # ... add it to both list and set.
        if value not in seen:
            output.append(value)
            seen.add(value)
    return output

# Remove duplicates from this list.
list = [[5, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
result = remove_duplicates(list)
print(result)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in <module>
  File "python", line 7, in remove_duplicates
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How do I fix this?
It says it cannot has a list, and I understand I have lists inside of lists, but How do I get the function to work?

Comment: Are you trying to remove lists from the list or individual values contained in the sublists? To be more precise: In the list you show there is no duplicate sublist, however, there are several 1s, 4s and 5s; are you trying to remove those?

Comment: If the first: `set(map(tuple, l))`, if the second: `from itertools import chain set(chain.from_iterable(l))`. If you want to keep lists: `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, l))))`.

Comment: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in <module>
  File "python", line 3, in remove_duplicates
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
`

Comment: Ducky, is your goal to remove every number in the sublists if they appear anywhere else?

Comment: `l` is your `list`. Don't use `list` as variable name as it is a built-in.

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work. Same error as showed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the lists into tuples, and then cast the list of tuples into set, and then cast the tuples into list.

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
list(map(list,set(map(tuple,lst))))

>>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tuple`s  instead: `seen.add(tuple(value))`

The reason is that list are modifiable, and sets are storing elements in a hash table so if you modify the entry, it modifies its hash, but it won't update the set. So modifiable types like lists are forbidden as keys in sets and dicts.

And of course, do the `tuple` change each time you want to check if something is in the set.

Comment: What's the error message then? If `value` is a list, then `tuple(value)` turns it into a tuple.

Comment: See my update, should work if you apply the same pattern.

Comment: this changes the double brackets one one set of brackets and one of parenthesis, I do not want parenthesis

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just change `if tuple(value) in seen`. Just everything that has `value` and `seen`.

Comment: I changed every value to tuple(value)
`[(5, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)]`

Comment: Don't, just the two places I mentioned, where I gave you the exact code you need.